# logs are showing a succesful handshake but not connecting

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, firewall, putty

I am using putty on windows to connect to an external ubuntu box:

```
putty.exe mylogin@somewhere.com -pw mypassword
```

The logs from pfsense are showing that it allowed this traffic to pass; however, I am getting this message:

[image]

I am able to remotely control the target machine using teamviewer.

The firewall logs are showing a succesful passthrough

[image]

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to establish port forwarding. When you have a connection coming in on port 22, it should be forwarded to the ssh server.